# Fourier transformation of image in only 1 dimension

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

I have the following image: `img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/Peu6mwd.png"]`

Each column shows the y coordinate of some objects (each row is 0.012 mm apart) and the horizontal coordinate corresponds to the time (one column is 1/35 sec). One can see a general drift from top to bottom with time.

Expressed in plot with axes this is:

[image]

**I want to display an image showing the FFT amplitudes vs. frequency for each y coordinate.**

My code is the following:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/Peu6mwd.png"];

{dimx, dimy} = ImageDimensions[img]; 

dy = 0.012; 
dt = 1/35; 

fftData = Abs[Fourier[Flatten@ImageData@ImageTake[img, {#, #}, {0, All}], 
     FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]] & /@ Range[dimy]; 

fftImg = 
 ImageTake[Image@Rescale[fftData, {0.00001, 0.005}], 
  All, {1, dimx/2}]; 

Graphics[
 Inset[Colorize[fftImg, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], Scaled[{.5, .5}],
   Automatic, Scaled[1]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y (mm)", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 35/2}, {0, dimy*dy}}, 
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@fftImg]
```

which gives:

[image]

Do you know a better solution especially to replace the calculation of `fftData`?. IDL e.g. allows to call the FFT with dimension=1. I did not find any integrated mathematica function.

Comment: "Better" in what way?  Faster?  Smaller?  More colors?  Something else?  What is the metric for "Better" in your context?

Comment: I don't think you need `ImageTake`. Just use `Fourier /@ ImageData[img]` to transform every row in your image or `Transpose[Fourier /@ Transpose[ImageData[img]]]` to transform every column. (I have no idea what the rest of the code does.)

Comment: Use `Map`. `fft=Rescale[Abs[Fourier[#,FourierParameters->{-1,1}]&/@data][[All,1;;Floor[dimx/2]]],{0.00001,0.005}];
Colorize[Image[fft],ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way that's pretty close to your approach:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/Peu6mwd.png"];
imgData = ImageData[img];
imgDims = Dimensions[imgData];
all = Table[fft = Abs[Fourier[imgData[[i]]]]; fft[[1]] = 0;
   fft[[1 ;; 50]], {i, 1, imgDims[[1]]}];
MatrixPlot[all, AspectRatio -> 1/2] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Each row shows the FFT of the corresponding row of the image. This sets the first coefficient to zero because it was large and made the details harder to see. It also plots just the first 50 terms because after about 100 there is not much to see.

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice solution.